# sessionFactory not being injected. It's always null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, spring-boot

I'm sessionFactory on my service.

```
@Component
public class MyService {    

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

public void persistData(){
  ...

  tx.commit();
  session.close();
}
```

I call this service from

```
@Component
public class CommandLineApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MyService MyService

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        MyService.persistData();
    }

}
```

My main class that start spring boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
   }

}
```

When I call MyService it's getting the error nullPointException. When I debug the code I can see that the sessionFactory is null. Why is sessionFactory is not being injected on MyService?

Comment: Where exactly would the instance of `SessionFactory` come from. You would need some sort of a provider that creates the instance, because as far as I know non of the `Spring` projects exposes a `SessionFactory` by default. You should on the other hand be able to get an instance of `EntityManagerFactory` if you are auto-configuring `Spring Data JPA`.

Comment: Are you doing everything here? http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring

Comment: I'm able to use java config class with spring boot?

Comment: It simple cannot be `null` if Spring cannot fulfill an `@Autowired` field your application will fail to startup. So you are probably creating a new instance of the service.class yourself. Next to that don't use plain hibernate use JPA (unless you really want to configure things yourself instead of letting Spring Boot do the hard work for you).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the `SessionFactory` bean is still not
available to the spring container for you to inject.
So first you need to bootstrap it.
Create an @configuration file 
or add @Configuration to your Main.java and bootstrap your beans like below

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateSessionProvider {

  @Bean  // If using hibernate.cfg.xml
  public void getSessionFactory() {
    AnnotationSessionFactoryBean annotationSessionFactoryBean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
    ...
    return annotationSessionFactoryBean()
  }

  @Bean  // If using java based config to provide DataSource beans , hibernate config  
  public void getSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    ...
    return localSessionFactoryBean()
  }
}
```